# Sniffing router's WiFi traffic

Tags: wifi, router, wpa2

Let's say someone already has my key and is logged in my wifi network and also has access to my router. Catching the four-way handshake for the hacker is important to see my web traffic. If he wants to see my traffic/log from the router I suppose it's the same thing: he also has to catch the four-way handshake right?

Answer (score 1):

If the attacker have control of your wifi router he/she just need to capture the traffic with tcpdump on the corresponding network device.

Comment: But even on a router log the https websites are not visible except for the hostname right?

Comment: That depends on your router logs in general, but for HTTPS you will see some information related to the handshake and certificate, the rest is encrypted if is proper HTTPS